# Sub-dictionary erroneously repeated throughout dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to store in a dictionary the number of times a given letter occurs after another given letter. For example, `dictionary['a']['d']` would give me the number of times `'d'` follows `'a'` in `short_list`.

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
short_list = ['ford','hello','orange','apple']

# dictionary to keep track of how often a given letter occurs
tally = {}
for a in alphabet:
    tally[a] = 0

# dictionary to keep track of how often a given letter occurs after a given letter 
# e.g. how many times does 'd' follow 'a' -- master_dict['a']['d']
master_dict = {}
for a in alphabet:
    master_dict[a] = tally

def precedingLetter(letter,word):
    if word.index(letter) == 0:
         return
    else:
         return word[word.index(letter)-1]

for a in alphabet:
    for word in short_list:
        for b in alphabet:
            if precedingLetter(b,word) == a:
                 master_dict[a][b] += 1
```

However, the entries for all of the letters (the keys) in `master_dict` are all the same. I can't think of another way to properly tally each letter's occurrence after another letter. Can anyone offer some insight here?

Comment: Instead of writing the whole alphabet into a list, you could just `from string import ascii_lowercase` and then `alphabet = list(ascii_lowercase)`.

Comment: I did that; just included the list for demonstration.

Comment: Even if you fix the problem you're asking about, your code won't run because a `ValueError: substring not found` will be raised in `precedingLetter()` whenever the `letter` doesn't occur in the `word`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sub-`dict`s are all supposed to be updated independently after creation, you need to shallow copy them. Easiest/fastest way is with `.copy()`:

```
for a in alphabet:
    master_dict[a] = tally.copy()
```

The other approach is to initialize the `dict` lazily. The easiest way to do that is with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

masterdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

# or

from collections import Counter, defaultdict

masterdict = defaultdict(Counter)
```

No need to pre-create empty tallies or populate `masterdict` at all, and this avoids creating `dict`s when the letter never occurs. If you access `masterdict[a]` for an `a` that doesn't yet exist, it creates a `defaultdict(int)` value for it automatically. When `masterdict[a][b]` is accessed and doesn't exist, the count is initialized to `0` automatically.

Comment: As an aside, I'm getting `0` down the diagonal in my calculation above, but I think the `if precedingLetter(letter,word) == a` statement should account for that, right? Like in the case of `aardvark`, shouldn't the `aa` be accounted for?

Comment: With the first approach, instead of doing a `tally.copy()` for each entry in `master_dict`, wouldn't it be simpler to just use a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/[library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object to hold the associated counts?

Comment: @martineau: Yeah, probably. It's mostly a slower (implemented in Python instead of C when using CPython reference interpreter) version of `defaultdict(int)` with support for special `set`-like behaviors and count related features. If you use those features, then `Counter` is great, if you don't, it's slower to no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to the first answer it could be handy to perform your search the other way around. So instead of looking for each possible pair of letters, you could iterate just over the words.

In combination with the `defaultdict` this could simplify the process. As an example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

short_list = ['ford','hello','orange','apple']
master_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for word in short_list:
    for i in range(0,len(word)-1):
        master_dict[word[i]][word[i+1]] += 1
```

Now `master_dict` contains all occured letter combinations while it returns zero for all other ones. A few examples below:

```
print(master_dict["f"]["o"]) # ==> 1
print(master_dict["o"]["r"]) # ==> 2
print(master_dict["a"]["a"]) # ==> 0
```

Comment: I think using `defaultdict(int)` is preferable to `defaultdict(lambda: 0)`, but otherwise you make an excellent point about simplifying the process of finding all the letter pairs that occur. It's would not only be simpler, it would also be much faster.

Comment: @martineau I am lacking experience in this, so could you briefly explain, why using `int` would be the better choice? Probably a performance issue, too? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. All `defaultdict`  needs as an argument is a callable, and Python classes are callable, so providing class `int` means it will call `int()` which will return one with a default value of `0` whenever a value is requested for a key that doesn't exist. While your code accomplished the same thing, it's longer and constructs an unnecessary anonymous function that must be called in order to accomplish the same thing. Put another way, `lamba: 0` can be replaced by a built-in which are almost always faster.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you ask about is that the `master_dict[a] = tally` is only assigning the same object another name, so updating it through any of the references updates them all. You could fix that by making a copy of it each time by using `master_dict[a] = tally.copy()` as already pointed out in [@ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623282/355230).

As @ShadowRanger goes on to point out, it would also be considerably less wasteful to make your `master_dict` a `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` because doing so would only allocate and initialize counts for the combinations that actually encountered rather than all possible 2 letter permutations (if it was used properly).

To give you a concert idea of the savings, consider that there are only 15 unique letter pairs in your sample `short_list` of words, yet the exhaustive approach would still create and initialize 26 placeholders in 26 dictionaries for all 676 the possible counts.

It also occurs to me that you really don't need a two-level dictionary at all to accomplish what you want since the same thing could be done with a single dictionary which had keys comprised of tuples of pairs of characters.

Beyond that, another important improvement, as pointed out in [@AdmPicard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624176/355230), is that your approach of iterating through all possible permutations and seeing if any pairs of them are in each word via the `precedingLetter()` function is *significantly* more time consuming than it would be if you just iterated over all the successive pairs of letters that actually occurred in each one of them.

So, putting all this advice together would result in something like the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase

alphabet = set(ascii_lowercase)
short_list = ['ford','hello','orange','apple']
# dictionary to keep track of how often a letter pair occurred after one other. 
# e.g. how many times 'd' followed an 'a' -> master_dict[('a','d')]
master_dict = defaultdict(int)

try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)  # 2 independent iterators
    next(b, None)                          # advance the 2nd one
    return izip(a, b)

for word in short_list:
    for (ch1,ch2) in pairwise(word.lower()):
        if ch1 in alphabet and ch2 in alphabet:
            master_dict[(ch1,ch2)] += 1

# display results
unique_pairs = 0
for (ch1,ch2) in sorted(master_dict):
    print('({},{}): {}'.format(ch1, ch2, master_dict[(ch1,ch2)]))
    unique_pairs += 1

print('A total of {} different letter pairs occurred in'.format(unique_pairs))
print('the words: {}'.format(', '.join(repr(word) for word in short_list)))
```

Which produces this output from the `short_list`:

```
(a,n): 1
(a,p): 1
(e,l): 1
(f,o): 1
(g,e): 1
(h,e): 1
(l,e): 1
(l,l): 1
(l,o): 1
(n,g): 1
(o,r): 2
(p,l): 1
(p,p): 1
(r,a): 1
(r,d): 1

A total of 15 different letter pairs occurred in
the words: 'ford', 'hello', 'orange', 'apple'
```